# How to read choosen file content in Cordova app?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

I want to perform the below task in my Cordova android app

- Give the user the ability to choose any txt file from his device.
- Then the file content I need to read in my app
- Modify file content and store it in another txt file

For Choosing text file I have used

```
cordova-plugin-filechooser
```

And written code as below

```
fileChooser.open(function (uri) {
  alert(uri);      
});
```

Which correctly opens the dialog to choose a file. After choosing the file I am getting uri as below

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/446
```

Now how I should read the file content? I am also using

```
cordova-plugin-file
```

I have checked code for cordova-plugin-file and we need to use `fileEntry`, how should I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use instead [cordova-plugin-filepath](https://github.com/hiddentao/cordova-plugin-filepath) then do

```
let path = FilePath.resolveNativePath('content://...', successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: Thank you Eric for the answer, used filepath plugin and got the path like file:// now how should I read the file content? How should I create FileEntry object?

Comment: Then use "cordova.file.applicationDirectory" of file plugin to get the file